# join or merge two xml documents and match content

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have two xml documents

sample1.xml:

```
<products>
    <product>
        <productid>001</productid>
        <title>Apple</title>
    </product>
    <product>
        <productid>002</productid>
        <title>Samsung</title>
    </product>
</products>
```

sample2.xml

```
<prices>
    <product>
        <productid>001</productid>
        <price>500</price>
    </product>
    <product>
        <productid>002</productid>
        <price>300</price>
    </product>
</prices>
```

My goal is join two xml files in one file by matching id's.
like that:

```
<products>
    <product>
        <productid>001</productid>
        <price>500</price>
        <title>Apple</title>
    </product>
    <product>
        <productid>002</productid>
        <price>300</price>
        <title>Samsung</title>
    </product>
</products>
```

I've simply find a way to merge two xml files but output wasn't like that.
Any idea would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: https://eval.in/598512

Comment: @splash58 thank you so much! It works!

Comment: @splash58 Please can you post your answers as answers, with the code on the site, so they can be read by others? You can include a link to eval.in or similar alongside the code if you like. Comments are intended as a temporary space to clarify the question (or an answer), not as a replacement for the answer itself.

Comment: @splash58 may i ask one more question? What about if there is more than two xml? I just add $str3 here: https://eval.in/598573 thanks in advance.

Comment: @linepisode  the same aproach - make array with is points to object and combime a result

Comment: @IMSoP You can do it from your name or from community :)